# Why i cant move(locate) the button

Tags: java, layout

i try to locate my buttons in frame to center, or, if to be honest, make my layout more flexible. But when i set properties like as `.setBounds`, my buttons have no reaction. Why? Thx for any help!

```
import com.sun.beans.editors.ColorEditor;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    public class windowsInterface extends JFrame{

        windowsInterface(){
            super("When the nearest HB");
            setSize(800, 800);
            JPanel panelForAddDel = new JPanel();
            panelForAddDel.setSize(800, 100);
            panelForAddDel.setLocation(0, 0);
            panelForAddDel.setBackground(Color.gray);

            JTextField nameOfStaff = new JTextField();
            JTextField dateOfBirth = new JTextField();


            JButton addRec = new JButton("Добавить");
            addRec.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 50);
            JButton delRec = new JButton("Удалить");
            delRec.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 50);

            addRec.setBounds(320, 125, 200, 50);
            delRec.setBounds(420, 125, 200, 50);



            JPanel panelForWatch = new JPanel();
            panelForWatch.setLocation(0, 100);
            panelForWatch.setSize(800, 600);
            panelForWatch.setBackground(Color.BLUE);



            add(panelForAddDel);
            add(panelForWatch);


            panelForAddDel.add(nameOfStaff);
            panelForAddDel.add(dateOfBirth);
            panelForAddDel.add(addRec);
            panelForAddDel.add(delRec);


        }
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest you start with using a simple `FlowLayout` on your panel. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working code examples you can download and play with.

Answer (score 2):

> But when i set properties like as .setBounds, my buttons have no reaction. Why?

Because there is a default layout in the Java Components. For instance, JFrame uses a default BorderLayout manager which determines how your added components within the JFrame will position and overrules your `setBounds()` methods, hence giving you the impression that it isn't working.

You will realise that if you remove this layout by setting it to null `this.setLayout(null)`, `setBounds()` will seem to function again.

However, it is recommended that you choose an appropriate layout based on your needs instead of using null layout.

- I would recommend you to add your components to a JPanel and add the JPanel to the JFrame instead of adding directly into the JFrame.
- Set an appropriate layout for your JPanel
- If needed, you can use nested JPanels with each having different layout to meet your needs.

Comment: i tried to do it. But i don't understand where i should turn on  'layout' property! I tried to set it in front of button - no result, tried to do this to panel - and the same situation( May be u can point the finger where i should type this property.

Comment: In your constructor, be it a customized JFrame or JPanel. If you use JPanel, it already has a default FlowLayout which I think you can try it out and see how it works before experimenting other layouts.

Answer (score 2):

This might be because the default layout for panel is flow layout. Read about it
 http://www.javatpoint.com/FlowLayout. A more flexible layout is GridBagLayout you can change the layout of panels or JFrames to your choice. 
To learn about GridBagLayout: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_gridbaglayout.htm